# Proving boundedness of a sequence using Mathematical Induction

Tags: real-analysis, induction

> If $a_1 = 1$, $a_n = \frac{3a_{n-1} + 2}{6}$, for all $n \ge 2$, then prove that $a_n \ge \frac{2}{3}$ and $a_n \ge a_{n+1}$ for all $n \ge 1$.

I have not solved much problems using Mathematical Induction and hence cannot proceed any further.

Comment: What have you done/tried so far?

Comment: Isn't the second statement false? If $a_1 = 1$, then $a_2 = 5/6 < 1$.

Comment: Sorry, that's a typo.

Answer (score 1):

I will prove the first statement and leave the second one to yourself.

**Base Step** For $n=1$ we get $a_1 = 1 \geq 2/3$.

**Induction Step** Assume that $a_k \geq 2/3$ for some $k \in \mathbb{N}$. Then, 
\begin{align}
a_{k+1} = \frac{3a_{k} + 2}{6} \geqslant \frac{3(2/3) +2}{6} = \frac{4}{6} = 2/3.
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

Hint for the second statement: $\;\;a_1=1 \gt \frac{5}{6}=a_2\,$, then:

$$\require{cancel}
a_{n+1}-a_{n}=\frac{3a_n+\bcancel{2}}{6}-\frac{3a_{n-1}+\bcancel{2}}{6}=\frac{1}{2}(a_n-a_{n-1})
$$